# convert utf-8 in sting into character

Tags: c#, utf-8

How can i convert a string that contain UTF8 encode into a string that contain only character ?
At the beginning I have a UTF8 string example : "Thành" but after some action i perfom it convert all UTF8 character into UTF8 encode ( in this case it convert "Thành" into "Th&#224;nh" ). How can i convert it back to origin string ? ( convert "Th&#224;nh" into "Thành" ). I'm using c#. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you see is encoded with XML/HTML [numeric character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference), nothing to do with UTF-8. You can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode it.